# Effectively Create a Matrix from a Dataframe for Large dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, bigdata, reshape2, melt

I am trying to create a matrix from a large dataframe. Here is a sample dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(index=c("x","y","j","ww","rr","ff"),
             a=c(1,3,3,5,1,6), 
             b=c(2,3,5,3,2,3),
             c=c(3,2,4,5,6,10),
             d =c("ha1","ha2","ha3","ha4","ha5","ha"))

> df
  index a b  c   d
1     x 1 2  3 ha1
2     y 3 3  2 ha2
3     j 3 5  4 ha3
4    ww 5 3  5 ha4
5    rr 1 2  6 ha5
6    ff 6 3 10  ha
```

The matrix need to look like this.

```
> matrix
   a b  c
ff 6 3 10
j  3 5  4
rr 1 2  6
ww 5 3  5
x  1 2  3
y  3 3  2
```

So, the approach that I used is to first change the dataframe structure to something like this using melt

```
df1 <- reshape2::melt(data = df, id.vars = c("index","d"), variable.name = "colname", value.name = "value")

> df1
   index   d colname value
1      x ha1       a     1
2      y ha2       a     3
3      j ha3       a     3
4     ww ha4       a     5
5     rr ha5       a     1
6     ff  ha       a     6
7      x ha1       b     2
8      y ha2       b     3
9      j ha3       b     5
10    ww ha4       b     3
11    rr ha5       b     2
12    ff  ha       b     3
13     x ha1       c     3
14     y ha2       c     2
15     j ha3       c     4
16    ww ha4       c     5
17    rr ha5       c     6
18    ff  ha       c    10
```

And then do acast

```
matrix <- acast(df1, index~colname, value.var="value")
```

The above approach works, but now I am dealing with big dataset and when the data is converted using melt (df1) it becomes really big and crashes.

So is there any way I can do this effectively in creating a matrix from the dataframe df, without even having an intermediate step.

Comment: Isn't this removing the first column, convert to matrix with `as.matrix` and changing the rownames as the first column? i.e. `'row.names<-'(as.matrix(df[-1]), df[,1])`

Comment: Is there a logic why the row order is changed in the expected output

Answer (score -1):

Based on the output, we can remove the first column which is a `character` column, convert the rest of the dataset to `matrix` and assign the row names with the first column

```
m1 <- `row.names<-`(as.matrix(df[-1]), df[,1])
str(m1)
# num [1:2, 1:3] 1 3 2 3 3 2
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:2] "x" "y"
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
m1
#  a b c
#x 1 2 3
#y 3 3 2
```

---

If we use `tidyverse`, then `column_to_rownames` is useful

```
library(tidyverse)
column_to_rownames(df, "x") %>%
      as.matrix
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset, we can apply the same logic after subsetting the numeric columns

```
`row.names<-`(as.matrix(df[2:4]), df[,1])
```

If there are many `numeric` columns and it is difficult to get the index, loop through the columns to get the index of numeric columns and use that for subsetting

```
m2 <- `row.names<-`(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], df[,1])[order(df[,1]),]
m2
#   a b  c
#ff 6 3 10
#j  3 5  4
#rr 1 2  6
#ww 5 3  5
#x  1 2  3
#y  3 3  2
```

Comment: Thanks for jumping in. But this is a very minimal example, and I have many more columns.

Comment: @JohnG It is not clear when you show a simple example.  Can u update your pots with a bit more complex example that mimics the issue

Comment: @JohnG It only needs to subset the columns if I am right `'row.names<-'(as.matrix(df[2:4]), df[,1])`

Comment: got it. The main thing is I need to have control on the rowname and colname ..Say for instance using acast acast(df1, index~colname, value.var="value") , the "index" will be my rownames and "colname" will be my columnname..

Comment: @JohnG I understand your point, but I am thinking that it would be inefficient to do a `melt` followed by `cast` if the end goal is to have a matrix with some selected columns